# Git LFS - error pushing despite files in question listed when querying "git lfs ls-files"

Tags: git, git-lfs, git-fork-client

This is an existing repo that already has LFS set up.
The .gitattributes file contains the following:

```
# Macros
[attr]lfs           -text filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs

...

# Video
*.asf                lfs
*.avi                lfs
*.flv                lfs
# Images
*.bmp                lfs
*.BMP                lfs
*.exr                lfs
# Compiled Dynamic Library
*.dll               lfs
*.pdb               lfs
```

I'm showing this as an example.

I've recently downloaded a package that contains large files. I've set them up to be tracked under git LFS, and when querying "git lfs ls-files" the files are listed in the response.

However, when I push, I get the following:

```
remote: error: File Assets/Vuplex/WebView/Standalone/Mac/Plugins/WVMac/Contents/Frameworks/VuplexWebView.app/Contents/Frameworks/ChromiumEmbeddedFramework.framework/ChromiumEmbeddedFramework is 170.54 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB        
remote: error: File Assets/Vuplex/WebView/Standalone/Mac/Plugins/WVMac_wCodecs.bundle/Contents/Frameworks/Vuplex.app/Contents/Frameworks/ChromiumEmbeddedFramework/ChromiumEmbeddedFramework is 183.87 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB        
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
```

The files in question don't have extensions and their path is complicated, however I'm reluctant to mess around with them too much in case this breaks the package.

There's a support article from the package itself here:
https://support.vuplex.com/articles/git-large-files

Which I've followed without success.

I'm using Fork as a git client, but have also tried pushing via the command line.

I've tried these steps:
https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-large-files/resolving-git-large-file-storage-upload-failures

And I've tried editing the .gitattributes file so that the files are listed in there using the same 'lfs' attribute that is used for the other files.

I've tried setting the entire folder (Assets/Vuplex) to be tracked by LFs using
git lfs track "Assets/Vuplex/**"

Answer (score 0):

Resolved via Fork client.
Right click on relevant files when you first go to commit them -> LFS -> track.
Not sure how this can be done once the files have already been committed.